# With RSA, can one ensure that two entities will not have the same private key?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, rsa

With the RSA encryption algorithm, is there any guarantee that two different entities will not be given the same private keys?

Comment: The things that generate and store users' private keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probability.

When generating a 1024-bit RSA keypair, one of the first jobs is to pick a pair of primes *p* and *q* such that the product of those numbers (i.e. *p* multiplied by *q*) is 1024 bits in size. The simplest way to do this is to pick both values to be somewhere around 512 bits in size each, as 2<sup>512</sup> × 2<sup>512</sup> = 2<sup>1024</sup>. Note that I'm picking 1024-bit as it's now considered to be the lowest acceptable key size, in which you're going to have the highest likelihood of prime collision.

Now, if we assume that *only* 512-bit values are used for *p* and *q*, we can now estimate how many primes there are in that range. I [discussed this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25241/rainbow-table-concept-for-prime-numbers) in an answer to another question about RSA, but I'll re-iterate here. The [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) allows us to estimate the number of primes in a given range. It isn't really defined, as it's just an estimation, and there are various ways to compute it. The simplest and roughest way is simply *π(x) = x / ln(x)*, where π is the PCF and `ln()` is natural log. As I explained in the linked answer, there are likely somewhere around 1.885×10<sup>151</sup> prime numbers in the range 2<sup>512</sup> < n < 2<sup>513</sup>.

This means that, assuming an ideal implementation, the chance of picking equal p or q values in two independently generated RSA key pairs is roughly one in...

> 18,850,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

That's slightly less likely than winning the jackpot on the [UK national lottery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lottery_%28United_Kingdom%29) 21 draws in a row (13,983,815<sup>21</sup> = 1.143×10<sup>150</sup>).

---

This is all assuming that the implementation is ideal. However, this isn't always the case. For example, there used to be [a bug in OpenSSL](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2008-0166) that caused uninitialised stack data to be used as the random pool for generating RSA primes, which meant that the actual number of possible outputs from the RNG was quite small. The resulting key pairs are now blacklisted from most implementations to prevent exploitation. Another example is that in many embedded devices (e.g. firewall appliances, routers, etc.) certain cryptographic values, such as SSH session keys, are generated early on in the system boot process, when there isn't much entropy available. This leads to a situation where the number of possible generated keys is *significantly* lower than you might expect, potentially leading to prediction attacks.

---

The tl;dr is that the key space is so large that randomly selecting two equal primes (p or q) when independently computing two RSA key pairs is phenomenally unlikely.

Comment: Note that in most cases, the RNG is actually a PRNG over a random seed, so the risk of collision is much bigger -- though still overwhelmingly small (if it is not, then your RNG is using a very poor or way too small seed).

Comment: The prime counting function is "really defined", it just isn't really defined _as_ x/ln(x).

Comment: We just don't have an efficient algorithm for calculating it for arbitrary x. :)

Comment: + for embedded/etc ref https://factorable.net/ . But you have the bug backwards: upstream OpenSSL (then) seeded partly from "leftover" stack data and worked decently, but a Debian packager *commented out* the use of uninit var because analysis tools complained (and in most programs it is indeed a bug) leaving *almost no* entropy. https://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571 https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html

Comment: @RickyDemer That is true, though when I said "isn't really defined" I was referring to the fact that (as Stephen pointed out) we don't have a defined, agreed upon function for calculating its true value, short of actually counting all the primes, which defeats the point of the PCF in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, statistics. The chances of generating two identical private keys in an environment with good randomness are effectively nil.

Comment: I think "good randomness" should be underlined, in bold, and in a 120pt font. :p

Comment: Even with only "fair randomness" or just "randomness" not only would one have to discover they have the same key as someone else, they have to realize they have the same key as someone else. It's essentially the same thing as with keys to bike locks. There are probably over 100 people in the US alone that have the same exact keys to their bike locks, but the manufacturers ship them to different regions and states and the odds of someone in Florida realizing and exploiting the fact that they have the same key as someone in California even more astronomical. Could it happen? Yes, anything COULD.